# Chrome 49 - display flex issue in windows 10 when scrolling

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll, rendering, flexbox

When scrolling, I noticed a rendering issue after updating Google Chrome. It seems like it is rendering the page too slow. 
My version of Chrome is 49 and my operating system is Windows 10. (This did not happen in Linux, Mac or Windows 7). It is using the CSS property: display flex.

Has anyone else encountered this issue as well?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 hates Chrome. It seems like Microsoft is intentionally attempting to make others use their browser, "Edge", because of how slow they have made Chrome run. On any other operating system, it runs flawlessly on an even 4gb of RAM. On Windows 10, you'll be waiting every bit of 5-10 minutes just for the "about:blank" page to load, not even trying to get the internet yet.

With this in mind, I'm almost sure that this is something to do with Windows 10 being itself. I've had multiple rendering issues on Chrome myself on the operating system.

I'm also with Michael_B on this, the comment above. It looks like it could be a bug in Chrome but I wouldn't be surprised if Microsoft didn't contribute to this somehow.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Its really frustrating to think that microsoft will do such things on purpose, especially after all the years we suffered with microsoft Explorer

Comment: It really does. I'm surprised that they've hit such a low that they're stuck slowing down other programs just to get others to use theirs. @Er85